# bs_modal doesn't work in flexdashboard's sidebar

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

## `bsplus::bs_modal()` creates a modal dialog popup, and works within a column, but not a sidebar.

Any ideas on how to make (1) work?

For reference, the `bs_modal()` source is [here](https://github.com/ijlyttle/bsplus/blob/master/R/modal.R), and `flexdashboard.js` is [here](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/blob/feature/logo-and-favicon/inst/rmarkdown/templates/flex_dashboard/resources/flexdashboard.js).

---

### (1) This works:

````html
---
title: "Untitled"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------


```{r}

```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
bs_modal(id = "modal", title = "I'm a modal", body = "Yes, I am.")
bs_button("Click for modal") %>%
  bs_attach_modal(id_modal = "modal")
```
````

### (2) This doesn't work:

````html
---
title: "Untitled"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
```

Sidebar {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------


```{r}
bs_modal(id = "modal", title = "I'm a modal", body = "Yes, I am.")
bs_button("Click for modal") %>%
  bs_attach_modal(id_modal = "modal")
```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```
````